# Azure Redis Cache as a datastore?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles, azure-redis-cache

I am developing a PaaS. The application will be hosted in Azure websites. Currently I am using EF / SQL as a datastore with in memory caching. I was planning on using the Azure Reddis Cache if the application grows and I need to share this cache across multiple instances.

As I looked more into reddis I started to like what I saw. It was really fast and perfect for a number of my domain objects. My logging model for instance. So now I am wondering, can I use Azure Reddis Cache as a primary data store ?

The word ***Cache*** in the name has me concerned. Is the data purged when not being used?

---

###### Application

The app is a MVC5 app. It includes a HtmlController administration section but the meat of the work is in an ApiController. The ApiController will serve mostly OData Get's, but I will have my share of PUT requests as well. I bill **by request**, so all user actions must be logged (a perfect job for reddis).

My model has three objects and no relations. User's which is used infrequently for authentication. Logging which is 90% put 'fire and forget', and Storage which is partitioned by 'app key' and 'group key'. Storage 'sets' will be requested and the Odata verbs will be applied manually in memory.

---

Would Azure Tables would be a better solution?

Comment: There might be right, it does sound like a technical question to me as well. What you could do is reach out to your Local MS office and make a connection with someone from DPE (Development Platform Evangelism). They tend to help easier and answer those kind of questions.

Comment: Features supported and not supported by their Redis install should be on the front page. Last night I found a potential answer in an hour long video. The answer was it 'could possibly' save to Azure Tables 'now or in the future'.

Comment: It's still a preview service, it takes sometime to build all the features and announce everything. I don't believe that it will save to Azure Table to be honest. More likely the aof file will be saved on Azure Blob storage, so you can backup/restore etc. from there. I haven't heard anything of saving to Azure tables.

Comment: Oh and btw, this is not really a "feature" but more like an implementation detail. As I said before, if they say "cache" I would treat it as volatile unless stated otherwise.

Comment: Here is my source for the Azure Tables.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/A-look-around-the-Redis-Cache-Preview-with-Saurabh-Pant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Redis as a primary data store but there is always a small risk of data loss, between the time Redis receives data and by the time it tries to write it to the AOF file. If during that window, the instance dies, you'll lose that portion of the data.

Having said that, there is no clear indication if Azure Redis Cache does background saves or not (in simple words, writing to the disk). If they don't then everything stays in memory on the servers, meaning if you lose all the servers, you lose all the data. Losing all the servers is an highly unlike scenario, but still possible.

Until there is further information, I would go with the assumption that data can be lost from the cache (volatile) and have another type of data store (e.g. SQL as you do now) to be safe.

**UPDATE**: Redis Cache does not have persistence enabled, so the original assumption was correct.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. Ill try putting this in a direct email to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/) an interesting post about disadvantages of using MongoDB as primary source instead of relational database.

I think most of conclusions take place in your scenario as well.

Most important issue - if you need or will need in future to find connections and relationships between data, calculate metrics and extract business values from data, then using solutions like Redis could cause problems, because they designed to store and retrieve SINGLE values, without relationships to other data.

Comment: This was education. My data has no relations, but, I do need to requests sets of data using OData verbs. The sets are partitioned by 'user key' and the OData verb-age can be done in memory.

Comment: You can de-normalize data and save them in flat structures along with their relationships. That is NoSQL 101. Also, with Redis you can retrieve multiple keys that contain multiple values, not just 1 Single Key. You can stretch the limits by emulating relations (1st level, then it gets really complicated) with specially crafted keys e.g. USER_1_REL_14 and then with a LuA Script load all the data that are related with each other, by parsing the key. Mapping this to a structure in your code and you have 1st level relations. With the latest addition of Lex search, that can be even more flexible.